# Obtain latest data for each product

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a table that collects securities holdings data for Funds like below.

How do I extract latest data for each FundName?

| EffectiveDate | FundName | SecurityName | PercentageOfAssets |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30/06/2022 | Fund A | xxx | 33.33% |
| 30/06/2022 | Fund A | yyy | 33.33% |
| 30/06/2022 | Fund A | zzz | 33.33% |
| 31/07/2022 | Fund B | xxx | 50% |
| 31/07/2022 | Fund B | yyy | 50% |
| 31/08/2022 | Fund B | yyy | 50% |
| 31/08/2022 | Fund B | zzz | 50% |
| 31/07/2022 | Fund A | xxx | 50% |
| 31/07/2022 | Fund A | yyy | 50% |

What I'm expecting

| EffectiveDate | FundName | SecurityName | PercentageOfAssets |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31/07/2022 | Fund A | xxx | 50% |
| 31/07/2022 | Fund A | yyy | 50% |
| 31/08/2022 | Fund B | yyy | 50% |
| 31/08/2022 | Fund B | zzz | 50% |

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - plese correct your tags.

Comment: If you feel the answer is correct can you please accept the solution?

Answer (score 2):

This will get the expected output

```
;WITH CTE AS (    
    SELECT EffectiveDate, FundName, SecurityName, PercentageOfAssets
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FundName ORDER BY EffectiveDate DESC) AS RowNum
)    
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `cross apply` in SQL Server:

```sql
select t1.EffectiveDate, t1.FundName, t1.SecurityName, t1.PercentageOfAssets
from @tbl t1
cross apply (
    select t2.FundName, max(t2.EffectiveDate) maxEffDate
    from @tbl t2
    group by t2.FundName
) latest
where latest.FundName = t1.FundName
    and latest.maxEffDate = t1.EffectiveDate
order by t1.EffectiveDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a subquery that will get the `MAX` `EffectiveDate` then `JOIN` it to an outer query to return the rest of your rows:

```
SELECT b.MaxDate, a.FundName, a.SecurityName, a.PercentageOfAssets
FROM (
      SELECT FundName, MAX(EffectiveDate) as MaxDate
      FROM Funds
      GROUP BY FundName
) b
INNER JOIN Funds a
ON a.FundName = b.FundName
  AND a.EffectiveDate = b.MaxDate
ORDER BY a.FundName, a.SecurityName ASC
```

**Result:**

```
| MaxDate    | FundName | SecurityName | PercentageOfAssets |
|------------|----------|--------------|--------------------|
| 31/07/2022 | Fund A   | xxx          | 50%                |
| 31/07/2022 | Fund A   | yyy          | 50%                |
| 31/08/2022 | Fund B   | yyy          | 50%                |
| 31/08/2022 | Fund B   | zzz          | 50%                |
```

**Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Bo-CoUJp?hide=2).**

**Note:** This will work for both **MySQL** and **SQL Server**.